# New CPU Upgrade And Requirements To Run Software

Tags: processor, upgrade

I current have `AMD Athalon 2 X3 445` CPU on a `Gigabyte GA-MA770T-UD3 AMD 770 DDR3 1666(OC) Soket AM3 Anakart` motherboard. I haven't upgraded my PC In a while but I've just bought an Oculus Quest 2 AR Headset and I'm interested in creating some AR games using [Spark AR](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/downloads#spark-ar-player-app)

When I try and run Spark AR I get `"Spark AR Requires a CPU that supports SSE4.1 instructions"`

The minimum software requirements are below

Intel Core i3 2.5Ghz, or AMD Bulldozer/Jaguar/Puma/Zen with SSE4.1 instruction set. Processors produced in the last decade will likely support this instruction set.

so any recommendations on CPU and will I need a new motherboard?
What are my options from here?

Comment: In your place I would probably strongly consider doing a full platform upgrade and grabbing a Zen processor. Preferably Zen2 or wait some time and grab Zen3 which will be unveiled October 8th. Do you have a dedicated GPU?